# How to find someone online to collaborate on a joint paper?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I would like to know where (a website) I can find anyone to publish some joint papers?

I thought such cooperation can be shaped as the following:

- We could share some ideas for papers through email or a web tool and ask the opinions about them (in fact if the person is an expert on a field who could transfer his knowledge and experience to me and direct me in the right way would be a plus :) )
- I would try to prepare a draft of the paper

Somethings that I wish the other one can guide or help me on are:

- I don't know much journals to publish a paper in, in this regard one could send the article to the journal
- My English is not perfect and the other one could modify the paper or guide me for some modification

**Update:**
it seems the way I wrote it, the relation could be like two keen researchers with common field of interest or like an expert who guide a PhD student.

Comment: Are you an independent researcher, or are you in some sort of institution, like a university?

Comment: I am in a university and must mention the university affiliation

Comment: I don't think there is a 'dating site' for scientific collaboration. Maybe you could explain why you are looking for someone outside your university, is it because no one has the necessary expertise? That might increase the chances of getting meaningful answers here.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6035/how-do-researchers-from-different-institutions-collaborate/6037#6037.

Comment: If this is all you need, you should probably be looking for a Professional Editing Service, not a co-author....

Comment: Yes I need an expert on the fields of my interest, I modified the question

Comment: Are you studying a PhD? If you are, your supervisor should be your main collaborator in the first papers. If you are not yet, then you should search for a supervisor for your future master or PhD and (s)he should be your collaborator. If you have already finished the PhD, then there are many things that I don't understand and I cannot help you.

Comment: @Trylks No I have a master degree, but I teach in university, before to apply for PhD I must publish some papers, even I had a PhD, still some experts could guide and help me like a supervisor

Comment: Your update does not do what I assume you wanted: You recognise the ambiguity but you do not solve it.

Answer (score 18):

The things you seek from a coauthor (advice on journal selection and English usage) are not in themselves a sufficient basis for coauthorship, but rather just being thanked in the acknowledgments.  A coauthor on a scholarly publication needs to make a substantial intellectual contribution by being seriously involved in the research.

I do not know of any website designed for academics seeking coauthors, and I wouldn't recommend approaching it from the perspective of "I'd like to publish a paper and am looking for someone to help clean it up and submit it."  That's not likely to find you the sort of intellectual connection that would lead to genuine coauthors.  Instead, you may get no responses, or you may get unscrupulous coauthors who just want an easy way to get their names on papers.  (And even if that doesn't bother you, think about it this way: if someone's willing to put their name on your ideas, could you really trust them not to add some plagiarized text to the paper?)

Instead, research collaboration should come before coauthorship, so the question becomes how to find collaborators.  That can come in all sorts of ways: you can talk with people at conferences about common interests, you can write to people whose papers are on similar topics, etc.  Sometimes collaborators meet through participation in websites where they discover a common interest.  (They aren't necessarily collaborating on the website, but they may start to correspond after interacting through the website, and the correspondence may turn into a collaboration.)  Once you are actively working on research with someone, writing a paper together will come naturally.

Comment: 'unscrupulous coauthors who just want an easy way to get their names on papers' That was a pretty accurate prediction judging by the recent comment posted on the question...

Comment: Thank you much for your complete advice, yes you are right I must add that I need an expert on the field of my interest, but my other problem is that I am forced to publish some papers within one or two years, I thought such a person could fasten my efforts to publish some papers